# Getting Error If I Run Android Studio in Win 64 bit

Tags: android, win64

I have a problem with Android Studio.

> Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible
>   with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's
>   system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64
>   (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software
>   publisher

Comment: which version you are using in android studio?

Answer (score 0):

> Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible
>   with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's
>   system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64
>   (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software
>   publisher

It's because you are running a 32-bit version android studio application on a 64-bit machine. Try to run `studio64.exe` (which is inside **bin** folder of android studio).

[image]

Comment: Oh, but i use 32-bit machine @@!

Comment: Oh really, but your question title is saying something different.